# text font is automatically set and is not changing

Tags: php

My problem is that whenever i am linking this nav file to any other php file using - include'_navbar.php' my font style of whole text of that page is automatically getting changed i don't know why. I have not changed font and the font of whole page is getting changed as i include this file to any other file say `home.php` or `about.php`. please help me in a beginner friendly way

This is my _navbar.php

```
<?php

echo '<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <img height="20px" src="/houzz/_utilityimages/title.svg" alt="">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">HOUZZ</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/houzz/index.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Locations of destination
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">KOTA</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">JAIPUR</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">AJMER</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">LUCKNOW</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">DELHI</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">PATNA</a></li>
                        <!-- <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li> -->
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">GAYA<a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">AGRA</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">RANCHI</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/houzz/about.php">About Us</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex">
                <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search by city, Institute "
                    aria-label="Search" style="width:40vw">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="width:10vw">Search</button>
            </form>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mx-2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#loginModal">Login</button>
            <!-- <a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="/houzz/partials/_otp.php">Signup</a> -->
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" href="/houzz/partials/_otp.php">
                Sign Up
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>';
include '_login.php';
?>
```

Comment: If you inspect on the page where does the console show the color is coming from? You don't need to `echo` that. You can just have HTML in the PHP file e.g. `<?php include '_login.php'; ?>` after the `<nav` assembly

Comment: @user3783243 but what is the reason behind this font change even if I am not doing any kind of change anywhere related to fonts so why and from where it is arriving

Comment: @user3783243 I have echoed that because I have something to do in future in that na bar like some restrictions so I need to echo that and I think it doesn't harm the font

Comment: If you view developer console it will show where the style is coming from. If you know that is would likely be easier to figure it out. The `echo` is not needed, https://3v4l.org/AlgB6 would be the same..

Comment: @user3783243 I just visited the developers console and it is showing that this font style is due to user agent stylesheet. Now how to resolve the issue

Comment: So the HTML structure your page has defines the colors it is being. Make a style sheet and define them as you want.

Comment: @user3783243 I have already attached a style sheet made my me and there is no font style there so why is it coming???. I have made a file named indexstyle.CSS and I am linking this css to only index.php. I am not linking any CSS in navbar